# NSFireDelayedPerform calls '+[ABContactView preCacheEditCells]' and crash sometimes

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app will crash sometimes when start up in ios 7.1.2(ios6 and ios8 is ok), the stack trace shows that '+[ABContactView preCacheEditCells]' is called, but my app doesn't need to access address book, i don't know why this happens, could anyone give me some help?

**Logs:**

Feb  2 15:32:02 test-iPad MyAPP[6741] : *** Assertion failure in void _UIPerformResizeOfTextViewForTextContainer(NSLayoutManager *, UIView *, NSTextContainer *, NSUInteger)(), /SourceCache/UIFoundation/UIFoundation-264.8/UIFoundation/TextSystem/NSLayoutManager_Private.m:1510

Feb  2 15:32:03 test-iPad MyAPP[6741] : *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Only run on the main thread!'

```
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2dc94ecb 0x3875fce7 0x2dc94d9d 0x2e642e8b 0x35b2fe59 0x35b2fba3 0x35b2fc0d 0x35b5d711 0x3056bcc1 0x35b79367 0x35b5b559 0x35b5bb5b 0x35b2fca7 0x35b31823 0x35b324a5 0x35b5f15b 0x305698a1 0x35b35d2f 0x35b35da3 0x35b59fa5 0x35b795b1 0x3056973b 0x3056953b 0x30568df1 0x30699c4f 0x305bbe45 0x304dfaf1 0x305be497 0x2dbd938f 0x2dbd929f 0x304d076b 0x305bcae5 0x304c6555 0x304c62e5 0x3014231b 0x3013db3f 0x304db481 0x305fdfcf 0x2d2e9189 0x2d2cc3e1 0x2d2ee481 0x2e675117 0x2dc5ff0f 0x2dc5fb2b 0x2dc5deb3 0x2dbc8729 0x2dbc850b 0x2e5bc497 0x2e60d259 0x3053ef 0x2e5c9875 0x2e66d745 0x38c4d25f 0x38c4e689 0x38c4e8dd 0x38d79c17 0x38d79adc)
```

Feb  2 15:32:03 test-iPad MyAPP[6741] : *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Only run on the main thread!'

```
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2dc94ecb 0x3875fce7 0x2dc94d9d 0x2e642e8b 0x35b2fe59 0x35b2fba3 0x35b2fc0d 0x35b5d711 0x3056bcc1 0x35b79367 0x35b5b559 0x35b5bb5b 0x35b2fca7 0x35b31823 0x35b324a5 0x35b5f15b 0x305698a1 0x35b35d2f 0x35b35da3 0x35b59fa5 0x35b795b1 0x3056973b 0x3056953b 0x30568df1 0x30699c4f 0x305bbe45 0x304dfaf1 0x305be497 0x2dbd938f 0x2dbd929f 0x304d076b 0x305bcae5 0x304c6555 0x304c62e5 0x3014231b 0x3013db3f 0x304db481 0x305fdfcf 0x2d2e9189 0x2d2cc3e1 0x2d2ee481 0x2e675117 0x2dc5ff0f 0x2dc5fb2b 0x2dc5deb3 0x2dbc8729 0x2dbc850b 0x2e5bc497 0x2e60d259 0x3053ef 0x2e5c9875 0x2e66d745 0x38c4d25f 0x38c4e689 0x38c4e8dd 0x38d79c17 0x38d79adc)
```

...
...

**Crash:**

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                0x2dc94ecb __exceptionPreprocess + 131
1   libobjc.A.dylib               0x3875fce7 objc_exception_throw + 38
2   CoreFoundation                0x2dc94d9d +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 104
3   Foundation                    0x2e642e8b -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:] + 86
4   UIFoundation                  0x35b2fe59 -[NSLayoutManager(NSPrivate) _resizeTextViewForTextContainer:] + 376
5   UIFoundation                  0x35b2fba3 -[NSLayoutManager(NSPrivate) _recalculateUsageForTextContainerAtIndex:] + 1522
6   UIFoundation                  0x35b2fc0d -[NSLayoutManager(NSPrivate) _validatedStoredUsageForTextContainerAtIndex:] + 80
7   UIFoundation                  0x35b5d711 -[NSLayoutManager usedRectForTextContainer:] + 112
8   UIKit                         0x3056bcc1 -[_UITextContainerView textContainerOrigin] + 92
9   UIFoundation                  0x35b79367 -[NSTextContainer textContainerOrigin] + 162
10  UIFoundation                  0x35b5b559 -[NSLayoutManager _primitiveInvalidateDisplayForGlyphRange:] + 2848
11  UIFoundation                  0x35b5bb5b -[NSLayoutManager invalidateDisplayForCharacterRange:] + 438
12  UIFoundation                  0x35b2fca7 -[NSLayoutManager(NSPrivate) _invalidateDisplayIfNeeded] + 62
13  UIFoundation                  0x35b31823 -[NSLayoutManager(NSPrivate) _rectArrayForRange:withinSelectionRange:rangeIsCharRange:singleRectOnly:fullLineRectsOnly:inTextContainer:rectCount:rangeWithinContainer:glyphsDrawOutsideLines:rectArray:rectArrayCapacity:] + 5866
14  UIFoundation                  0x35b324a5 -[NSLayoutManager(NSPrivate) _rectArrayForRange:withinSelectionRange:rangeIsCharRange:singleRectOnly:fullLineRectsOnly:inTextContainer:rectCount:rangeWithinContainer:glyphsDrawOutsideLines:] + 80
15  UIFoundation                  0x35b5f15b -[NSLayoutManager rectArrayForCharacterRange:withinSelectedCharacterRange:inTextContainer:rectCount:] + 58
16  UIKit                         0x305698a1 -[_UITextContainerView updateInsertionPointStateAndRestartTimer:] + 244
17  UIFoundation                  0x35b35d2f -[NSLayoutManager(NSPrivate) _invalidateLayoutForExtendedCharacterRange:isSoft:invalidateUsage:] + 1966
18  UIFoundation                  0x35b35da3 -[NSLayoutManager(NSPrivate) _invalidateLayoutForExtendedCharacterRange:isSoft:] + 30
19  UIFoundation                  0x35b59fa5 -[NSLayoutManager textContainerChangedGeometry:] + 324
20  UIFoundation                  0x35b795b1 -[NSTextContainer setSize:] + 152
21  UIKit                         0x3056973b _UITextContainerViewResyncNSTextContainer + 298
22  UIKit                         0x3056953b -[_UITextContainerView setFrame:] + 134
23  UIKit                         0x30568df1 -[UITextView _resyncContainerFrameForNonAutolayout] + 328
24  UIKit                         0x30699c4f -[UITextView setBounds:] + 390
25  UIKit                         0x305bbe45 -[UIView(Geometry) _applyISEngineLayoutValues] + 280
26  UIKit                         0x304dfaf1 -[UIView(Geometry) _resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 164
27  UIKit                         0x305be497 -[UIScrollView _resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 42
28  CoreFoundation                0x2dbd938f __53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 90
29  CoreFoundation                0x2dbd929f -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 198
30  UIKit                         0x304d076b -[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 118
31  UIKit                         0x305bcae5 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _is_layout] + 136
32  UIKit                         0x304c6555 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutSubviews] + 72
33  UIKit                         0x304c62e5 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 380
34  QuartzCore                    0x3014231b -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 142
35  QuartzCore                    0x3013db3f CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 350
36  UIKit                         0x304db481 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 552
37  UIKit                         0x305fdfcf -[UITableViewCell setEditing:animated:] + 654
38  AddressBookUI                 0x2d2e9189 -[ABContactCell setEditing:animated:] + 76
39  AddressBookUI                 0x2d2cc3e1 -[ABPropertyCell setEditing:animated:] + 76
40  AddressBookUI                 0x2d2ee481 +[ABContactView preCacheEditCells] + 408
41  Foundation                    0x2e675117 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 414
42  CoreFoundation                0x2dc5ff0f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 14
43  CoreFoundation                0x2dc5fb2b __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 794
44  CoreFoundation                0x2dc5deb3 __CFRunLoopRun + 1218
45  CoreFoundation                0x2dbc8729 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
46  CoreFoundation                0x2dbc850b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
47  Foundation                    0x2e5bc497 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 254
48  Foundation                    0x2e60d259 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 80
49  MyAPP                        0x003053ef 0x4000 + 3150831
50  Foundation                    0x2e5c9875 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 772
51  Foundation                    0x2e66d745 __NSOQSchedule_f + 60
52  libdispatch.dylib             0x38c4d25f _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 110
53  libdispatch.dylib             0x38c4e689 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 228
54  libdispatch.dylib             0x38c4e8dd _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 56
55  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x38d79c17 _pthread_wqthread + 298
56  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x38d79adc start_wqthread + 8


Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x38d141f0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x38d7c7b3 pthread_kill + 55
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x38cc4ff5 abort + 73
3   libc++abi.dylib               0x3811398b abort_message + 71
4   libc++abi.dylib               0x3812c6e3 default_terminate_handler() + 251
5   libobjc.A.dylib               0x3875ff7b _objc_terminate() + 191
6   libc++abi.dylib               0x3812a1b1 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 77
7   libc++abi.dylib               0x38129d13 __cxa_rethrow + 99
8   libobjc.A.dylib               0x3875fe2b objc_exception_rethrow + 39
9   CoreFoundation                0x2dbc879b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 639
10  CoreFoundation                0x2dbc8507 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
11  GraphicsServices              0x32af46cf GSEventRunModal + 135
12  UIKit                         0x3052986d UIApplicationMain + 1133
13  MyAPP                        0x0009c3bb 0x4000 + 623547
14  libdyld.dylib                 0x38c5dab5 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x38d01804 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib             0x38c50051 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 229
2   libdispatch.dylib             0x38c4a2df _dispatch_mgr_thread + 35

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x38d14c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x38d79c1f _pthread_wqthread + 307
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x38d79ad8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3 name:  com.xyz.abc
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x38d042b8 sigprocmask + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x38cc4fd9 abort + 45
2   libc++abi.dylib               0x3811398b abort_message + 71
3   libc++abi.dylib               0x3812c6e3 default_terminate_handler() + 251
4   libobjc.A.dylib               0x3875ff7b _objc_terminate() + 191
5   libc++abi.dylib               0x3812a1b1 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 77
6   libc++abi.dylib               0x38129d13 __cxa_rethrow + 99
7   libobjc.A.dylib               0x3875fe2b objc_exception_rethrow + 39
8   CoreFoundation                0x2dbc879b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 639
9   CoreFoundation                0x2dbc8507 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
10  Foundation                    0x2e5bc493 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 251
11  Foundation                    0x2e60d255 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 77
12  MyAPP                        0x003053eb 0x4000 + 3150827
13  Foundation                    0x2e5c9871 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 769
14  Foundation                    0x2e66d741 __NSOQSchedule_f + 57
15  libdispatch.dylib             0x38c4d25b _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 107
16  libdispatch.dylib             0x38c4e685 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 225
17  libdispatch.dylib             0x38c4e8d9 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 53
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x38d79c15 _pthread_wqthread + 297
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x38d79ad8 start_wqthread + 4
```

.....
.....

part of my code:

```
@implementation HttpOperation

- (void)main
{  
    [[NSThread currentThread] setName:@"com.xyz.abc"];

    // loop timer
    NSTimeInterval reportPeriod = 120;
    NSTimer *loopTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:reportPeriod
                                                          target:self
                                                        selector:@selector(periodReport)
                                                        userInfo:nil
                                                         repeats:YES];

    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:loopTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    while (TRUE) {
        if ([self isCancelled]) {

            break;
        }

        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];

    }

}

...

@end
```

Comment: Based on your crash report, it looks like you're trying to resize a text view on a background thread...

Comment: the reason for updating ui on background thread is that 'NSFireDelayedPerform calls +[ABContactView preCacheEditCells]', but my code doesn't do this, why does this happens?

Comment: well without seeing any code, it's difficult to say.

Comment: @rebello95 hi, code is added, please hava a look. thanks

Comment: where is your `-periodReport` code?

Comment: crash happens immediately after app finish launch, the timer is not fired yet, so periodReportt is not executed yet.